# Как словить нажатие на любой элемент на странице?

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть страница, в данном случае на ней кнопки:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Button</title>
        </head>
        <body>
           <button></button>
           <button></button>
           <button></button>
        </body>
</html>
```

Нужно на javascript словить onClick по любой из этих кнопок.

```
<button onClick="Function"></button>
Это не вариант
```

При этом элементы на странице динамически добавляются и удаляются.

На данный момент я придумал вот что:

```
document.onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName == "BUTTON"){
        console.log(e.target);
    }
};
```

Но здесь проблема такова: если внутри `<button>` есть ещё один тэг, то мы попадаем на него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Смотрим пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ef7903zL/)

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'), function(but){
    but.addEventListener('click', function(){
        // действия по клику
    }, false);
});
```

**UPD** Забыл про динамические элементы. [Пример с динамикой](http://jsfiddle.net/ef7903zL/1/)

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON'){
        // чего-то творим
    }
}, false);
```

**UPD 2** [Проверяем](http://jsfiddle.net/ef7903zL/7/) работу без учета дочерних элементов

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    while (target && target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') {
        target = target.parentNode;
        if(!target) return false;
    }
    // тут что-то делаем по клику на кнопку или его дочерним элементам
}, false);
```

Comment: Отлично! По сути, то что нужно. Но, прошу простить за нагласть, есть ли ещё варианты?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, для того, чтоб искать альтернативу, нужно знать причины того, почему эти варианты не устраивают.

Comment: @Станислав Далинин jquery-way

    $('body').on('click', 'button', function () {});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ef7903zL/4/ №кнопка номер 2 не срабатывает. Я писал в вопросе почему. А никто не знает, как реализовано это в jQuery?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, @Etki точно знает :)

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, смотрите [этот вариант][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/ef7903zL/7/

Comment: Да с циклом я тоже делал, мне не нравится это, с точки зрения оптимизации будет сильно грузить? Если на сайте будет какая-то програмная анимация на `requestAnimationFrame`, как будет влиять на неё цикл? И вообще неужели вам в ваших пректах не нужно было никогда реализовывать ajax загрузку страниц, ведь там влюбом случае нужно ловить нажатия на ссылки,  как вы справлялись с этим!?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, во-первых, ничего нагружающнго в этом цикле нет и близко. Если вы ждёте магию, то у меня её нет.

Comment: А жалко, с новым годом)))

Answer (score 0):

Присваивать каждому новому элементу id, и потом писать обработку по клику в <script> не вариант?

Comment: Нет, это ещё хуже, чем `<button onClick="Function"></button>`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте просто искать элементы по их id.
`<script> 
document.getElementById("demo").htmlInner = действие;
</script>
<button id="demo"></button>`
[Информация тут.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp)

Comment: Нет, это не будет работать и не `htmlInner` а `innerHTML`))))